# How to register for a Grid Column's Hide Event Extjs

Tags: extjs4.1, extjs4.2

Does anyone know how/where to register for a grid column's hide event? I want to know when a grid's columns have been hidden or unhidden.

I see nothing in Columns.js 
I do see something in Ext.grid.ColumnModel but how do I register for the hiddenchange event in my controller?

My grid is just a simple grid with columns defined in the columns array.

```
columns: [
       {//ID
            xtype:'templatecolumn', 
            tpl:'some template',
            header: 'ID',
            hideable:true,
            width:30,
            hidden:false,
            ...
            //other stuff
       },
       ...
       {
        //other columns
       }
```

What I want to do is in my controller register to be notified when a user has hidden a column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the controller register for your grids columns events

```
control = {
'#gridId gridcolumn':{ 
    beforehide:function( ths, eOpts ){
      //do whatever
    },
    beforeshow:function( ths, eOpts ){
      //do whatever
    }
}
```

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-event-beforehide
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-event-beforeshow

Not sure how I missed this...guess I was staying up to late.